# Javascript, how to select option when .selectedIndex is unknown

Tags: javascript, applescript

I am trying to use a combination of applescript and javascript to select and option from a dropdown select menu when the .selectedIndex is not known.

```
tell application "Safari"
activate
tell document 1
    do JavaScript "document.getElementsByName('dropdown')[0].selectedIndex=2"
end tell
end tell
```

This would select the 3rd option from a dropbdown menu (jelly) like this:

```
<select name="dropdown">
<option value="shoe">shoe</option>
<option value="man">man</option>
<option value="jelly">jelly</option>
</select>
```

However my issue is that the dropdowns are always changing for example, I could go one day and it could look like this:

```
<select name="dropdown">
<option value="billy">billy</option>
<option value="shoe">shoe</option>
<option value="man">man</option>
<option value="jelly">jelly</option>
</select>
```

This time the 'man' option would be selected.

Comment: Im on my phone at the moment, but you could try `.value='shoe'`?

Comment: doesnt seem to work within my applescript for some reason

Comment: There is also the more complicated `document.querySelector('[name=dropdown] [value=jelly]').selected=true;`

Comment: got it working using getElementId but no joys as yet

Comment: `document.getElementByID('dropdown').value='" & settrimsize & "';"` `set settrimsize to "jelly"`

Comment: just missed of the s 'getElementsByName'

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
set valuex to "jelly"
tell application "Safari"
activate
tell document 1
    do JavaScript "document.getElementsByName('dropdown')[0].value='" & valuex & "';"
end tell
end tell
```

Comment: Thank you for posting an answer to this question! Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow, because a code dump with no context doesn't explain how or why the solution will work, making it difficult for the original poster (or any future readers) to understand the logic behind it. Please, edit your question and include an explanation of your code so that others can benefit from your answer. Thanks!